# sh: 1: python: not found when execute python script from php

Tags: python, php, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I'm tring to execute a python script call from php with the command below:

```
$output = shell_exec('python /var/www/html/sna/server/userManagement.py '. $user.' '. $pass .' \''.$action.'\' 2>&1');
```

But when I execute it I get this

```
sh: 1: python: not found
```

But python is correctly installed in my env.

If I digit

```
type -a python
```

I get the path of python in this env like below

```
python is /home/leonardo/miniconda2/envs/sna/bin/python
```

At the very beginning of the python script I have include

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

But I recieve always the same error. How can I solve ?

Comment: Simply call Python providing the full path (in your a virtual env)

Comment: @Anonymous simply I love you. Thanks a lot, now it's work fine !

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comment of @Anonymous:

> Call Python providing the full path (in your virtual environment).

PS: A comment is not an answer. If you search, this question without an answer is less interesting, although it has the answer in its comments. That is why I copied it. All credits go to the other user.